# Uniform convergence of: $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n},\text{ with } x\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Does the function defined by: 
$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n},\text{ with } x\in\mathbb{R}$  converge uniformly in $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a sequence of continuous functions $f_n:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, converging poinwise to a function which is discontinuous at $x=0$. If the convergence was uniform this could not happen.

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} 1, & x=0\\ 0, & x \ne 0 \end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Every nonzero point must converge to $0$, but for any $n$, a sufficiently small positive $x$ satisfies $f_n(x) > \frac{1}{2}$. So the function does not uniformly converge.